# How to change multiple files with similar name in same folder?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have over 100 text files in a C:\General folder with similar name that all start the same just have a unique date at the end of it. How do I change the extension of the file to something else in a batch file?

I have tried multiple ren such as

````
ren "New Text%.txt" "New Text%.iif"
ren %~dp0New*.txt %~dp0TestChange*.iif

```
ren %~dp0New*.txt %~dp0TestChange*.iif
```
````

When running this as a batch file, I expect to see the following in C:\General

> New Text Document060119.iif
>   New Text Document060219.iif
>   New Text Document060319.iif
>   New Text Document060419.iif
>   New Text Document060519.iif
>   New Text Document060619.iif

In reality I see no change or copies of the files

> New Text Document060119.txt
>   New Text Document060219.txt
>   New Text Document060319.txt
>   New Text Document060419.txt
>   New Text Document060519.txt
>   New Text Document060619.txt

Comment: `Ren "%~dp0New*.txt" *.iif` should change the extensions for you. If you wanted to append additional text, then you'd need to run them through a `For` loop and rename each one through that.

Comment: Thanks Compo, that changed the extension. If I wanted to make a copy before renaming your saying use a For loop. Can you give an example of this as I have not used this yet.

Comment: Well to create copies, you'd simply use `Copy` instead of `Ren`, `Copy /Y "%~dp0New*.txt" *.iif`. Technically, as my provided comment answers your original question, that would be a different question. If you'd care to provide an example of how you'd like `New Text Document060419.txt` to look after renaming it, and confirm whether there could be other `.txt` files whose name begins with `New` in the source directory, `%~dp0` it would certainly help.

Comment: The `ren` command only accepts a pure file name (mask) as the second argument without a path (so `%~dp0` needs to be removed). Replacing a fixed prefix by `ren` does not work unless the new and the old ones are equally long: `ren "%~dp0old*.txt" "new*.iif"` works, but `ren "%~dp0some*.txt" "other*.iif"` does not. Though there is a useful [quirck](https://superuser.com/a/475875) when the new prefix is shorter: `ren "%~dp0some*.txt" "/new*.iif"` should then do it...